# USB Debugging mode auto authorize

Tags: android, adb, rsa, usb-debugging

I have LG Optimus L70, the system stopped working suddenly.

The problem was that the bootloader is corrupt, so I have to install a new one.

In order to do that, it would be easier to enable USB debugging mode, but the problem is:

When ever I check **USB Debugging** the phone vibrates indicating that it is connected to PC, when i go to **Device Manager** on windows, it showed that the device is connected as Single ADB Interface.

The key problem that the phone's system is corrupt even after hard resetting it, so no pop up is shown, so, no **RSA** authorizing pop up is shown.

How can I automatically accept RSA? or make my device usable in **ADB** at least?

I have tried all other posts mentioned here in stackoverflow, but non of them seems to solve the problem.

Comment: what version of android?

Comment: Kit kat, i think it is 4.3.2 or something 4.2.3 xD

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Developer -> Revoke authorizations usb debugging

Comment: Doesn't work either, the problem is that the system doesn't show the pop up for the authorization. Thank you tho ^_^